# What keys does Python-RQ use on the redis server?

Tags: python, redis, queue

I'm using a redis server both for queueing worker jobs and for a cache, and since I don't want key conflicts, I want to know what key names Python-RQ uses to store its data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is hidden in the contrib tab, under internals [here](http://python-rq.org/contrib/),

> All jobs are stored in Redis under the `rq:job:` prefix, for example
>
> `rq:job:55528e58-9cac-4e05-b444-8eded32e76a1`

Further reading shows that all metadata is stored there, so the answer is only keys which start with `rq:job`, so you (or I?) should be safe.

Comment: I actually needed the answer to this question until I found it for myself (after doing rigorous research, of course)